# NSNotification errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I seem to be stuck on NSNotification for some reason.

I am posting a notification in a IBAction button method. When the user taps that button, I want to be notified about it so I can set a text in a text field. Without them tapping the button, the NSString would still be nil - which is why I need to know when they do it.

So in the button method I have this:

```
- (IBAction)suggestionsButton:(UIButton *)sender {

    self.usernameSelected = sender.titleLabel.text;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UserTappedButton" object:self];
}
```

This is in a UITableviewCell class.

I then add the observer in the view controller that is concerned with this action:

```
 (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(userPickedAuserNameFromSuggestion:) name:@"UserTappedButton" object:nil];
}
```

Things I have checked:

1. That the observer method is called first before post method (It is )
2. That the name is correct on both methods
3. That the selector signature is correct

Looked at a few SO answers as well and hasn't helped.

Is there something I am missing here guys?

****UPDATE ****

Sorry - here is the method I want called:

```
-(void)userPickedAuserNameFromSuggestion: (NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog (@"Selected Username: %@", self.usernameCell.usernameSelected);

}
```

However its not being called

Comment: You don't say what the problem is.

Comment: can you show your method - userPickedAuserNameFromSuggestion

Comment: Are you sure that the `suggestionsButton:` method is being called when the user taps the button?

Comment: Updated the OP with method I want called. suggestionsButton is definitely called. I set a breakpoint and NSLog on it NSLog is called and execution stops on breakpoint.

Comment: `addObserver:` in `viewWillAppear` and `removeObserver:` in `viewWillDisappear`

Comment: Thanks. However this doesn't dove the issue, unfortunately.

Comment: just a suggestion.Can you try setting the object to nil while posting the notification and see if it works??

Comment: Tried that - still nothing. I'm going to remove all the code and just retype it. Maybe I have spelt something wrong somewhere. Thanks for the input

Comment: Okay - rewrote everything still nothing. Then I re added it to view willAppear per @Akhilrajtr's suggestion and now it works. Had it there before I moved it to viewDidLoad and it still wasn't working. Thanks all! Akhilrajtr please make your comment a question so I can mark it as answered.

Comment: I am getting the username from the UiTexField in a custom UITableViewCell and this is how I managed to set it in a different class. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Why are you using notification instead of just calling a method / calling a delegate method?

Comment: I'm not a fan of the overload of a delegate method for one simple NSString value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `-addObserver:` in `viewDidAppear` and `-removeObserver:` in `viewDidDisappear`

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //...
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(userPickedAuserNameFromSuggestion:)
                                                 name:@"UserTappedButton"
                                               object:nil];
    //...
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //...
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:@"UserTappedButton"
                                                  object:nil];
    //...
}
```

Comment: this doesn't really solve the issue at hand. infact, it makes it worse as it will prevent his `viewController` from getting the notification. (_also... it's not **absolutely** required to `removeObserver:` when the view disappears as there are certain scenarios where you may want the class to keep observing even when the view disappears_)

Comment: @staticVoidMan It is not required.But why keep observing the notification if the view is not displayed? It might be useless(except in some cases but I'm only interested in the notification if the view is actually displayed). And for this question this solved his problem(see comments), thats why I put this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Notification observer is not released correctly, you need to do this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"UserTappedButton" object:nil];
```

in `dealloc` function.